# Display Records With Non-Matching Values in a Column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am trying to create a query to find all duplicate values in a particular column (**ID**) and then display all of the values for only the records where the second column (**Name**) does not match.  The **Name** and **ID** fields (composite key) should be the same values across as many records created but I have found some records with different **Name**s using the same **ID**.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Williams</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td>2/13/2016</td>
    <td >11:39am</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Williams</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td>3/23/2016</td>
    <td>9:20am</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td >Johnson</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td >5/13/2016</td>
    <td >2:56pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Williams</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td>2/13/2016</td>
    <td>11:39am</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Jackson</td>
    <td>99999</td>
    <td>9/1/2016</td>
    <td >8:09am</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td >Smith</td>
    <td >77777</td>
    <td >10/10/2016</td>
    <td >3:03am</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The query should return the 3rd row (*the Johnson record*) as the record that does not match where there are duplicate **ID**s being used in multiple records.  I have tried different methods but not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to find where there is a name using an id usually used by another name.

```
create table [table] 
(
    Name varchar(50),
    ID int,
    [Date] date,
    [Time] time
);

insert into [table] values('Williams', 55555, '13-feb-2016', '11:39:00');
insert into [table] values('Williams', 55555, '23-mar-2016', '09:20:00');
insert into [table] values('Johnson', 55555, '13-feb-2016', '11:39:00');
insert into [table] values('Williams', 55555, '13-feb-2016', '11:39:00');
insert into [table] values('Jackson', 99999, '01-sep-2016', '11:39:00');
insert into [table] values('Smith', 77777, '10-oct-2016', '11:39:00');

with cte as (
    select id, name
    from [table]
    group by id, name 
    having count(*) > 1
)
select *
from [table]
inner join cte on [table].id = cte.id 
and [table].name != cte.name
```

EDIT: Added the data so I could verify the solution

Comment: Thanks @James-Casey. Yes, I am searching for records with names that do not match the historical Name, ID record set. I attempted a solution similar to your recommendation but it gave me the same results. Instead, it returns Name and ID records that are matching instead of the sets that are not matching.

Comment: I set up the table with the data you provided in your post, and the query returns Johnson for me. Can you identify how what you tried was different from the contrived example? Note the Johnson details are the first 4 cols of the result, the last two will be the cte i.e. showing who normally uses that id.